# Import table to hive using sqoop and oozie

Tags: sqoop, oozie

I'm testing oozie (v 4.1) using a sqoop (v 1.4) command which it's already tested. I've been through a few posts so I've been careful to put the sqoop jars into the share directory but I'm getting an annoying `Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]` error. I've also added the property `oozie.use.system.libpath=true` in the job.properties file.

My workflow.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1" name="sqoopTest">
    <start to="start-node"/>
    <action name="start-node">
        <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <command>import --connect jdbc:mysql://mysqldb.com/db --username user_name --password password --direct --table table_name --hive-import --hive-table db_hive.table_name --incremental append --last-value 0 --check-column id --append</command>
        </sqoop>
       <ok to="end"/>
       <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
     <kill name="fail">
        <message>Sqoop failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Anyone knows why that's happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you're missing the MySQL JDBC Driver JAR.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1" name="sqoopTest">
    <start to="start-node"/>
    <action name="start-node">
        <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <command>import --connect jdbc:mysql://mysqldb.com/db --username user_name --password password --direct --table table_name --hive-import --hive-table db_hive.table_name --incremental append --last-value 0 --check-column id --append</command>
            <archive>/tmp/mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar#mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar</archive>
        </sqoop>
       <ok to="end"/>
       <error to="fail"/>
    </action>
     <kill name="fail">
        <message>Sqoop failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Note the **<archive>/tmp/mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar#mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar</archive>**.

There should be more details in the launcher job task logs. See ingest.tips for an example of importing from [MySQL to Hive](http://ingest.tips/2014/11/27/how-to-oozie-sqoop-hive/).

Comment: I tried also following ingest.tips but no luck. Checking the job browser in hue I can see it creates two jobs the first one hangs when it gets to the 95% and the second one on a 0% progress. I've been able to read in the logs the data has been sqoop in hdfs as a temp file so it looks it's got some kind of problem connecting to hive although I think I've got all the jar files in place.